# forcing each to stop on error occur

Tags: jquery, each

how could I force $.each(arr, callback(key,value){...}) to stop when I found what I was looking for ?

If I can do that, could I stop with and do a callback with the last value found ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return false in your callback.

e.g.

```
var map = { 
  'flammable': 'inflammable', 
  'duh': 'no duh' 
}; 
$.each(map, function(key, value) { 
  alert(key + ': ' + value); 
  if (key == 'flammable') {
     //Do your result processing here (e.g. call another function)
     return false; //found
  }
});
```